# How can I filter for rows one hour before and after a set timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, timestamp, offset

I am trying to filter a DataFrame to only show values 1-hour before and 1-hour after a specified time/date, but am having trouble finding the right function for this. I am working in Python with Pandas.

The posts I see regarding masking by date mostly cover the case of masking rows between a specified start and end date, but I am having trouble finding help on how to mask rows based around a single date.

I have time series data as a DataFrame that spans about a year, so thousands of rows. This data is at 1-minute intervals, and so each row corresponds to a row ID, a timestamp, and a value.

Example of DataFrame:

```
ID            timestamp  value
 0  2011-01-15 03:25:00     34
 1  2011-01-15 03:26:00     36
 2  2011-01-15 03:27:00     37
 3  2011-01-15 03:28:00     37
 4  2011-01-15 03:29:00     39
 5  2011-01-15 03:30:00     29
 6  2011-01-15 03:31:00     28
...
```

I am trying to create a function that outputs a DataFrame that is the initial DataFrame, but only rows for 1-hour before and 1-hour after a specified timestamp, and so only rows within this specified 2-hour window.

To be more clear:

I have a DataFrame that has 1-minute interval data throughout a year (as exemplified above).

I now identify a specific timestamp: 2011-07-14 06:15:00

I now want to output a DataFrame that is the initial input DataFrame, but now only contains rows that are within 1-hour before 2011-07-14 06:15:00, and 1-hour after 2011-07-14 06:15:00.

Do you know how I can do this? I understand that I could just create a filter where I get rid of all values before 2011-07-14 05:15:00 and 2011-07-14 07:15:00, but my goal is to have the user simply enter a single date/time (e.g. 2011-07-14 06:15:00) to produce the output DataFrame.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
hour = pd.DateOffset(hours=1)
date = pd.Timestamp("2011-07-14 06:15:00")
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
df([date - hour: date + hour])
```

which returns:

```
File "<ipython-input-49-d42254baba8f>", line 4
    df([date - hour: date + hour])
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure if this is really only a syntax error, or something deeper and more complex. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

data = {"date": ["2011-01-15 03:10:00","2011-01-15 03:40:00","2011-01-15 04:10:00","2011-01-15 04:40:00","2011-01-15 05:10:00","2011-01-15 07:10:00"],
        "value":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')


date_search= dt.datetime.strptime("2011-01-15 05:20:00",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
mask = (df['date'] > date_search-dt.timedelta(hours = 1)) & (df['date'] <= date_search+dt.timedelta(hours = 1))
print(df.loc[mask])
```

result:

```
                 date  value
3 2011-01-15 04:40:00      4
4 2011-01-15 05:10:00      5
```